# Android Map Application is Crashing

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I'm trying to create a simple Map View Application. I went through [android developers documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key) and copy-pasted **MyActivity.java** class and **activity_main.xml** layout. The app is crushing when i start on my real device (Android v2.3.6). The package explorer, manifest file, and logcat errors are below.

[image]

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.timur.mapapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.timur.mapapplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.timur.mapapplication.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDQ4pnYq3on6WFJsE..." />

</manifest>
```

**LOGCAT ERRORS:**

```
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.timur.mapapplication/com.timur.mapapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:215)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at com.timur.mapapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    ... 11 more
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.timur.mapapplication-1.apk]
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
12-18 00:03:05.626: E/AndroidRuntime(18591):    ... 19 more
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please post your activity class and layout xml code

Comment: Maybe this stackoverflow entry will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437798/binary-xml-file-line-2-error-inflating-class

Comment: **SOLVED:** I used `SupportMapFragment` instead  `MapFragment`, and `FragmentActivity` instead `Activity`. The other mistake was the place of API_KEY. I placed it in `<application>` instead of `<manifest>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `MapFragment` when your `minSdkVersion` is set to 8. You should use `SupportMapFragment` instead like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Also, just a suggestion, do not post your API key, it should be kept private to whomever is developing the app.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't change, still forcing to stop.

Comment: google-play-services_lib is already in libraries and selected in 'order and export' tab.

Comment: Sorry, are you getting the same `Exception`?

Comment: Thanks for help. It worked. I used `SupportMapFragment` instead  `MapFragment`, and `FragmentActivity` instead `Activity`. The other mistake was the place of API_KEY. I placed it in `<application>` instead of `<manifest>`.

Comment: Glad to help. Please set this question as answered by selecting the answer that you feel fits best with your question.

Comment: It is working but there is just an error now: `E/dalvikvm(21983): Could not find class 'maps.ae.i', referenced from method maps.af.al.a
` Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

As Emmanuel suggested, change MapFragment to SupportMapFragment.

Adding to it, extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity in your java class. See if it works now.